# Запрет на прошивку телефона

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development

Каким образом, я могу запретить прошивать android. Используя кастомные рекавери и через комп.

Comment: Каким способом прошивать?

Comment: Запрет на любую попытку прошить телефон

Comment: есть как минимум три способа запретить. Как Эппл - просто не давать, юридически - бегать за всеми или просто переехать телефон катком. Последний способ достаточно надежен и прост.

Comment: @KoVadim Apple практически может запретить перепрошивку

Comment: Разберите телефон, и коннекты работающие на отладку отпаяйте, чтобы при подключении шла только зарядка

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете запретить прошивать телефон. Звучит примерно так же как и запрет на установку в компе другой ОС - скажем, вот стоит у вас на компе Windows - и вы хотите запретить установку на ней Linux'а... Ну разве что запрет на уровне железа и то сомневаюсь. Софтверно эта проблема не решается.